# SP2013 Missing Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, ribbon, publishing-page

I am using o365 sharepoint 2013 and have published custom masterpages and layouts. 
They are checked-in and published.

In subsites, when you go to page layout ribbon, all layouts appear apart from one. It used to appear but now it disappeared from the ribbon Change Pagelayout option. On the site collection root, it is there. However in subsites it is not.
- I did check that the pageloayout is available for the site from the settings page (Look and Feel > Page Layout and Site Template Settings)
- When I go to pages library, and create new page, the option is there.

So basically - The page layout is only missing in the ribbon under change page layout.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I fixed it.

For future information what I did is re-inherit the page layout settings from the parent (thus having all page layouts available again), and then breaking the inheritance again to restrict the subsites with the choices. This seems to have fixed (a possibly) broken reference between the ribbon and the page layout.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the content type of the missing page layout is set properly to "**Page Layout"**

If you are deploying it from visual studio it should be something like below

```
 <File Path="PageLayouts\PageLayoutOneCol.aspx" Url="WABOneCol.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE"  Level="Published" ReplaceContent="true">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="PageLayout - One Column"></Property>
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
      <Property Name="FeatureId" Value="$SharePoint.Feature.Id$" Type="string"/>
    </File>
```

To confirm it goto master page gallery and edit the page layout properties and set the right content type "Page Layout" and publish the page.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Its set as the others, still not showing.